# float number in php to javascript

Tags: php, javascript, locale

I am trying to set a point (lat/lon) with google API
I was doing something like

```
new LatLon(<?php echo (float)$lat ?>,<?php echo(float)$lng)?>);
```

But I discovered that on some servers, this was not working because

```
echo (float)1.1; ===== > display 1,1 (comma is the french separator for decimal)
```

Is that normal that the "echo" is not returning 1.1 ?? Is this something new in recent php version ?

should the correct solution be :

```
<?php echo json_encode((float)$lat)?>
```

Comment: tried checking in PHP's config?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `echo` uses the locale. Put this in your code before :

```
setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, 'en_US');
```

Depending on your needs, you might also want to simply set

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'en_US');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the floatval function to achieve that

```
<?php
$var = '122.34343The';
$float_value_of_var = floatval($var);
echo $float_value_of_var; // 122.34343
?>
```

you can also use number_format to specify the number of digits after the decimal point as below:

```
number_format($float_value_of_var,2); // 122.34
```

edit: my bad, dystroy above is right about setting the locale

Comment: Yes seems to be link to : setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, 'XXX.UTF-8'); The problem in my case if I want to be sure that whatever is the locale I want to return a dot separtor for the javascript !! I don't have the right to change the locale so I think json_encode is the simpler solution

Comment: yes, that's a clean way of doing it if you are limited to your locale. good luck!